# Bool issue - changing value

Tags: c#, boolean, boolean-logic

Morning all.

I have the following method that I use to to try and bring back a bool:

```
public static bool GetShowCatSubProdStatus(string memberid, string username)
    {
        MyEnts showcatsubprodstatus = new MyEnts.PDC_VDSOREntities35();

        var r = from p in showcatsubprodstatus.tblKeyAccountInfoes
                where p.MemberID == memberid && p.UserName == username
                select p.ShowCatSubProd;

        return r.Any();
    }
```

When I call this method and debug it, the result is correct. However, when I run this method in a page load, although the method result returns the correct result, when I step through, the boolean value changes!

```
 bool showcatsubprodstatus = MyEnts.GetShowCatSubProdStatus(_memberid, _username);

        if (showcatsubprodstatus != true)
        {
            panCatSubProd.Visible = false;
        }
```

Can someone explain what is going on here and how I can solve this puzzler?!

PS: Apologies for being thick.

EDIT - Right, narrowed it down to the variable. It is always return 'true' regardless of the method result?!?!

Comment: Can you confirm that is scoped as a *variable* (not a field). Also, do you use `showcatsubprodstatus` anywhere else, in particular in a lambda, LINQ expression, or anonymous method?

Comment: Hello Marc - yes it is scoped as a variable and apart from the if statement above, showcatsubprodstatus is not used anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code returns an `IEnumerable<bool>` :

```
var r = from p in showcatsubprodstatus.tblKeyAccountInfoes
        where p.MemberID == memberid && p.UserName == username
        select p.ShowCatSubProd;
```

By calling the `.Any()` you are asking it if there are any items in the IEnumerable. If there are you return true;

That is why you always get true back, because it always finds something.

**The solution**
Either you go for calling .SingleOrDefault() which returns the only element there is (if there is one) or returns the default value of that type.

```
var r = from p in showcatsubprodstatus.tblKeyAccountInfoes
        where p.MemberID == memberid && p.UserName == username
        select p.ShowCatSubProd;
return r.SingleOrDefault(); //assuming p.ShowCatSubProd is a bool and not a Nullable<bool> else you need to adjust your return type or cast it to a boolean using .GetValueOrDefault().
```

Comment: I love you Peter and want to have your babies : D

Comment: I had to use return r.FirstOrDefault().GetValueOrDefault(); however as I'm using LNQ to Entities which does not get on very well with Single/SingleorDefault.

Comment: you're welcome :-) Where I work we call these things 'sanity checks' and we ask a nearby sitting colleague to read through the code to spot things like this.